# I can't connect to my L2TP server from Windows and Android clients

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec, ubuntu-16.04, xl2tpd

On my Ubuntu 16.04 server `xl2tpd` service running successful.

My `/etc/ipsec.conf`:

```
version 2.0

config setup
    nat_traversal=yes
    oe=off
    protostack=netkey

conn L2TP-PSK
    authby=secret
    pfs=no
    rekey=no
    type=tunnel
    esp=aes128-sha1
    ike=aes128-sha-modp1024
    ikelifetime=8h
    keylife=1h
    left=51.15.67.126
    leftnexthop=%defaultroute
    leftprotoport=17/1701
    right=%any
    rightprotoport=17/%any
    rightsubnetwithin=0.0.0.0/0
    auto=add
    dpddelay=30
    dpdtimeout=120
    dpdaction=clear
```

My `/etc/ipsec.secrets`:

```
%any %any: PSK "MySecret"
```

My `/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf`:

```
[global]
ipsec saref = yes
[lns default]
ip range = 192.168.1.231-192.168.1.239
local ip = 192.168.1.230
refuse chap = yes
refuse pap = yes
require authentication = yes
ppp debug = no
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
length bit = yes
```

My `/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd`:

```
require-mschap-v2
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
asyncmap 0
auth
crtscts
lock
hide-password
modem
debug
name l2tpd
proxyarp
lcp-echo-interval 30
lcp-echo-failure 4
```

My `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`:

```
* * MyText *
```

My `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

`journalctl -xe` output:

```
Jun 05 14:29:07 vkmarket.ru kernel: random: nonblocking pool is initialized
Jun 05 14:29:08 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 11[NET] received packet: from 92.63.69.35[478] to 10.8.76.29[500] (444 bytes)
Jun 05 14:29:08 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 11[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V V ]
Jun 05 14:29:08 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 11[IKE] no IKE config found for 10.8.76.29...92.63.69.35, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
Jun 05 14:29:08 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 11[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1643143040 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Jun 05 14:29:08 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 11[NET] sending packet: from 10.8.76.29[500] to 92.63.69.35[478] (40 bytes)
Jun 05 14:29:11 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 12[NET] received packet: from 92.63.69.35[478] to 10.8.76.29[500] (444 bytes)
Jun 05 14:29:11 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 12[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V V ]
Jun 05 14:29:11 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 12[IKE] no IKE config found for 10.8.76.29...92.63.69.35, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
Jun 05 14:29:11 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 12[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 2523483634 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Jun 05 14:29:11 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 12[NET] sending packet: from 10.8.76.29[500] to 92.63.69.35[478] (40 bytes)
Jun 05 14:29:14 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 13[NET] received packet: from 92.63.69.35[478] to 10.8.76.29[500] (444 bytes)
Jun 05 14:29:14 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 13[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V V ]
Jun 05 14:29:14 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 13[IKE] no IKE config found for 10.8.76.29...92.63.69.35, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
Jun 05 14:29:14 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 13[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 3268885545 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Jun 05 14:29:14 vkmarket.ru charon[3375]: 13[NET] sending packet: from 10.8.76.29[500] to 92.63.69.35[478] (40 bytes)
Jun 05 14:29:36 vkmarket.ru systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device: Job sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device/start timed out.
Jun 05 14:29:36 vkmarket.ru systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device.
-- Subject: Unit sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device has failed.
--
-- The result is timeout.
Jun 05 14:29:36 vkmarket.ru systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device: Job sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Jun 05 14:29:36 vkmarket.ru systemd[1]: Startup finished in 19.348s (kernel) + 1min 30.912s (userspace) = 1min 50.261s.
-- Subject: System start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- All system services necessary queued for starting at boot have been
-- successfully started. Note that this does not mean that the machine is
-- now idle as services might still be busy with completing start-up.
--
-- Kernel start-up required 19348529 microseconds.
--
-- Initial RAM disk start-up required INITRD_USEC microseconds.
--
-- Userspace start-up required 90912634 microseconds.
Jun 05 14:35:01 vkmarket.ru CRON[3950]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 05 14:35:01 vkmarket.ru CRON[3954]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 05 14:35:01 vkmarket.ru CRON[3950]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 05 14:43:08 vkmarket.ru systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
Jun 05 14:43:08 vkmarket.ru systemd-tmpfiles[3979]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
Jun 05 14:43:08 vkmarket.ru systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your log I cannot see evidence of xl2tp running, maybe service is not started or active (configuration errors?).

Try this setup, it helped me a lot:
( source: [strongSwan + xl2tpd VPN server: how to configure several config files?](https://serverfault.com/questions/840586/strongswan-xl2tpd-vpn-server-how-to-configure-several-config-files) )

> Don't use the aggressive mode, the connection will be less secure.
>   Anyway try with this configuration. I use it on a my VPN Server with
>   strongswan-5.3.5 and xl2tpd-1.3.6
>
> ipsec.conf
>
> ```
> config setup
>     cachecrls=yes
>     uniqueids=yes
>     charondebug=""
>
> conn %default
>     keyingtries=%forever
>     dpddelay=30s
>     dpdtimeout=120s
>
>
> conn L2TP
>     dpdaction=clear
>   #Server IP
>     left=192.168.1.130
>   #Server default gateway
>     leftnexthop=192.168.1.254
>     leftprotoport=17/1701
>     rightprotoport=17/%any
>     right=%any
>     rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
>     leftauth=psk
>     rightauth=psk
>     leftid="<insert-the-public-ip-here>"
>     ikelifetime=1h
>     keylife=8h
>     ike=aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes128-md5-modp1536,aes128-md5-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1536,3des-sha1-modp1024,3des-md5-modp1536,3des-md5-modp1024
>     esp=aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes128-md5-modp1536,aes128-md5-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1536,3des-sha1-modp1024,3des-md5-modp1536,3des-md5-modp1024
>     auto=add
>     keyexchange=ike
>     type=transport
>
> conn block
>     auto=ignore
> conn private
>     auto=ignore
> conn private-or-clear
>     auto=ignore
> conn clear-or-private
>     auto=ignore
> conn clear
>     auto=ignore
> conn packetdefault
>     auto=ignore
> ```
>
> ipsec.secrets
>
> ```
> <insert-the-left-id-here> %any : PSK "<my-password>"
> ```
>
> /etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf
>
> ```
> [global]
> ipsec saref = no
> debug tunnel = no
> debug avp = no
> debug network = no
> debug state = no
>
>
> [lns default]
> ip range = 10.0.0.20-10.0.0.30
> local ip = 10.0.0.1
> require authentication = yes
> name = l2tp
> pass peer = yes
> ppp debug = no
> pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
> length bit = yes
> unix authentication = yes
> ```
>
> /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
>
> ```
> ipcp-accept-local
> ipcp-accept-remote
> ms-dns 10.0.0.1
> auth
> idle 1800
> mtu 1200
> mru 1200
> nodefaultroute
> lock
> proxyarp
> connect-delay 5000
> name l2tpd
> ifname l2tp
> login
> ```
>
> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
>
> ```
> username  *   "l2tppassword"  *
> ```
>
> restart services
>
> ```
> sudo service strongswan restart
> sudo service xl2tpd restart
> ```

Comment: The top half of your answer should be a comment, the bottom is a link-only answer. Link only answers are strongly discouraged. Link-rot may cause your answer to be useless in the future. Please include relevant information in your answer, with the link as a source reference.

Comment: With my actual rep I cannot put a direct comment (50 rep needed), the only way was to answer. You are absolutely right on the link-rot issue, but including all configuration files from the linked source would seem a copy&paste (stolen) answer (and very long post). I'm still trying to learn how to do here (non native english), it's quite a lot I'm around in reading mode but only few days I've started an account. Thank you for your hints.

Comment: If you are quoting information from a link, just use the block quote option and site that it is from your source. Comments are blocked from low rep users for a reason, the idea is that you are supposed to post some answers or questions to gain some rep, and then you can ask for more info in comments.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to follow your hints, thank you Cory